# В чем отличие двух функций?

Tags: python

```
def foo1(x=[]):
    x.append(1)
    print(x)

def foo2():
    x  = []
    x.append(1)
    print(x)
```

Почему при неоднократном вызове функции foo1() (без аргументов) получается вывод:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
...
```

Comment: похожий вопрос: [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница в том, что первая функция может принимать 1 агрумент, вторая не принимает аргументов. Советую прочитать [краткую информацию](http://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html) о функциях в Python.

Поведение, о котором Вы спрашиваете, происходит по такой причине, что значение по-умолчанию (пустой список) вычисляется единожды, когда функция была скомпилирована, затем оно используется при каждом вызове функции. Чтобы избежать такого поведения и получать пустой список при каждом вызове, измените код следующим образом:

```
def foo1(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = []
    x.append(1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что первая функция может принимать аргумент. Я не понимаю почему при нескольких вызовах foo1() (без аргументов) получаются выводы:
[1],
[1,1],
[1,1,1]
...

Comment: @ТолкачёвИван ну так и спрашиваете то, что не понимаете. Не надо издалека заходить. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: @ТолкачёвИван поправил ответ согласно уточнению в вопросе

Answer (score 3):

> Почему при неоднократном вызове функции foo1() (без аргументов) получается вывод

Аргументы по умолчанию создаются однажды и живут пока жива сама функция. Не используйте изменяемые объекты (такие как списки, словари) в качестве аргументов по умолчанию.

Если вы в `foo1()` ничего не передаёте, то у вас есть только один список `x` куда вы при каждом вызове добавляете новые элементы.

`foo2()` при каждом вызове создаёт новый список и прибавляет к нему один элемент.

Answer (score 2):

Если в двух словах, то так:

Аргумент по умолчанию будет **тем же самым объектом**, даже при разных вызовах функции. То есть, если вы изменяете этот объект в одном вызове функции, то он сохранит это новое значение при следующем вызове.

Это никак не проявляется, когда в качестве умолчания вы используете неизменяемые объекты (числа, строки, кортежи и т.п.)
Но это становится заметным, если в качестве умолчания вы используете изменяемые объекты (списки, множества и т.п.)

Поэтому обычно крайне не рекомедуется использовать изменяемые объекты как аргумент по умолчанию.